# Meteor 0.80 new template displaying only [object Object] on my app

Tags: meteor

This is all I see as rendered result: `[object Object]`

What do I have to modify?

My files:

**layout.html**

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {{yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**post_page.html**

```
<template name="postPage">
  <div class="sidebar col-md-4">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}
    <a class="save-all" href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="mainbar col-md-12">
    {{> postSubmit}}
  </div>
</template>
```

**post_page.coffee**

```
Template.postPage.helpers posts: ->
  Posts.find {},
    sort:
      position: 1
```

**routes.coffee**

```
Router.configure layoutTemplate: "layout"
Router.map ->
  @route "home",
    path: "/"
    template: "home"

  @route "postPage",
    path: "/posts/:_id"
    data: ->
      Posts.findOne @params._id
```

**post.coffee**

```
@Posts = new Meteor.Collection "posts"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 0.8 you need to do: `{{> yield}}` instead of `{{yield}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of Blaze, as describe [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/blaze-layout) and [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#advanced) you need to change the syntax of your template slightly:

**layout.html**

```html
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Router has been deprecated.  Use Iron-Router from meteorite, refer to the [docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)

```
Router.map(function() {
 this.route('postslist', {path: '/'})
//read the docs for your next routing needs
```

});

This is a similar post to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668110/meteor-path-helper-not-returning-anything/23668507?noredirect=1#comment36360510_23668507)